# $_COOKIE[Key] empty in spite of setting it

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I'm getting a problem concerning **php cookies**. I'm using recess framework to build a rest API.

I've 2 files involved

1. **User Controller**: a class containing methods having URLs for the model user
2. **CommentController**:same as user controller but for comments

class CommentController extends Controller
    {

```
    /** !Route GET, test */
    function test()
    {
        setCookie("Who","userId");
        exit;
    }

    /** !Route GET, cookie */
    function checkCookie()
    {
        print_r($_COOKIE);
        exit;
    }
}

class UserController extends Controller 
{

    /** @var User */
    protected $user;

    /** !Route GET, test */
    function test()
    {
      print_r($_COOKIE);
        exit;
    }
}
```

As you see, I've two files 1. Comment Controller 2. User Controller

i'm calling test from CommentController to set the cookie and checkCookie from same controller to check whether the cookie has been set, that ok, the cookie is set

But after calling these two functions, when i call test from usercontroller to check whether the cookie has been set, the cookie is not set

Comment: Hi, there someone who just down voted the question. I really have no problem if you down vote it, but at least leave a message and tell me why you down voted so that next time I don't make the same mistake :-)

Comment: In line `if (valid) setCookie("Who",$User->id);` , where is the value of `valid` set ??

Comment: in fact valid is an value i've just placed for clarity, in fact, i check from the database if the credentials is checked

Comment: Buzzword bingo. If you rely on cookies, then resource requests are no longer stateless. No REST. -- As for your question, why do you assume the setcookie function manipulates the $_COOKIE array?

Comment: complete code will be easier to debug

Comment: weps, I agree with you that it will no longer be stateless, but as far as REST is concern, there is no method that is truely rest for authentication, therz always a workaround. But it is stateless to a certain extent because we are using cookie only to carry userinfo, i'm not $_SESSION at no place in time!!

Comment: @tamilsweet, ok placing the complete code

Comment: I'm changing the whole question but same problem, it is simply a relaxed version of the problem

Comment: @Noor: With REST, the login credentials are usually provided and checked with each request.  That's one way you can do it statelessly, and more or less how HTTP's built-in authentication works.

Answer (score 3):

_COOKIE is only populated with the cookie data that was sent to the server by the client at the time the script was started. It will **NOT** be modified if you call setcookie() within th esame script execution session. Any cookies you modify/create during the current session will only show up in _COOKIE on the **NEXT** request the client makes.

As a general rule, PHP will populate the superglobals with the data it has at hand when the script starts up, and then it will not ever touch them again during that execution session. If you do anything that would affect a superglobal value, that new value will not show up in the corresponding superglobal until the next run.

Comment: in the first request I'm calling setcookie within the commentcontroller to set the cookie, then in a second request i'm sending a request again to commentcontroller to check if the request is set, this is ok, but in the third request when i send a request to usercontroller, it says cookie is not set

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with cookie path. You better make the cookie available for whole system.

Ex:

```
setcookie ("User", "999882", time() - 3600, "/public/", "test.com", 1);
```

Please try.

Prasad.

Comment: thanks for replying, when I'm setting the cookie using only setcookie ("User", "999882", time() - 3600, "/"), it is still not working even if it is for the entire domain, why?